# STR_TO_DATE discrepancy between MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date

This SQL returns a `DATE` in MySQL 5.5 but `NULL` in MySQL 5.6. Why?

```
select date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle for MySQL [5.5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eecb7db5/699) and [5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/40374). `STR_TO_DATE` returns a date in both instances. Converting the result using `DATE` works. The problem comes when trying to add an `INTERVAL`. It doesn't matter if I add an `INTERVAL` to `STR_TO_DATE(...)` or `DATE(STR_TO_DATE(...))`, the result is the same. However, removing the `STR_TO_DATE` makes it work.

```
select
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m') as same_a1,
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m') as same_a2,
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m-%d') as same_a3,
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') as same_a4,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m')) as same_b1,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m')) as same_b2,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m-%d')) as same_b3,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')) as same_b4,
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m') + INTERVAL 1 DAY as same_c1,
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m') + INTERVAL 1 DAY as same_c2,
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 DAY as same_c3,
    STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 DAY as same_c4,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY as different_d1,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY as different_d2,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01', '%Y-%m-%d')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY as different_d3,
    date(STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY as same_d4,
    date('2015-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY as same_e1,
    date('2015-01-01') + INTERVAL 1 DAY as same_e2
;
```

I searched the release notes but couldn't find anything. What is going on? Is this a known change? A bug?

Comment: For what it's worth, I see the same discrepancy between 5.1.73 and MariaDB 10.0.21.

Comment: With the MySQL CLI client instead of SQLFiddle, I see that `STR_TO_DATE()` produces a weird result when no day value is given:  `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2015-03')` produces `2015-03-00`.  I cannot add a date. The fact that it produces "day 00" in both older and newer versions seems wrong to begin with, but then the fact that you cannot add an interval to that invalid date without receiving NULL in later versions seems correct given the weird behavior. The older version allows me to add 1 day to "day 00", as `SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE('2015-03', '%Y-%m')) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;` resulting in `2015-03-01`

Comment: ^^... and that is _not_ the result I would expect. I would expect it to start from `2015-03-01` and add 1 day resulting in `2015-03-02`.

Comment: I have found some blog posts referring to the supported 00 day or 00 month value but no official docs other than for the well known zero date `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: "*The [`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) mode affects whether the server permits dates in which the year part is nonzero but the month or day part is 0.*"

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Also, the documentation for [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) itself states (my emphasis) "*Range checking on the parts of date values is as described in Section 11.3.1, “The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types”. This means, for example, that “zero” dates or **dates with part values of 0 are permitted** unless the SQL mode is set to disallow such values.*".   Of course, this isn't quite the same as dates with absent part values, but nevertheless is again official acknowledgement of 0 being valid in date parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known change, that was unwittingly introduced into versions [5.1.59](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-59.html), [5.5.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-16.html) and [5.6.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-3.html) (but was then rolled back in versions [5.1.62](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-62.html) and [5.5.21](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-21.html); it was retained in the 5.6 line):

> ***Incompatible Change:*** Handling of a date-related assertion was modified.
>
> However, a consequence of this change is that several functions become more strict when passed a [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function value as their argument and reject incomplete dates with a day part of zero. These functions are affected: [`CONVERT_TZ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz), [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), [`DAYOFYEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear), [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day), [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), [`TO_DAYS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days), [`TO_SECONDS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds), [`WEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), [`WEEKDAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday), [`WEEKOFYEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear), [`YEARWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek). Because this changes date-handling behavior in General Availability-status series (MySQL 5.1 and 5.5), it was reverted in 5.1.62 and 5.5.21. The change is retained in MySQL 5.6.
>
> References: See also Bug #13458237.

You are affected because the `+ INTERVAL` notation is just syntactic sugar around the `DATE_ADD()` function.

Comment: Incidentally, the change was reverted in the 5.6 line for `LAST_DAY()` only, at [5.6.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html).

Comment: +1 Thanks @eggyal! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I can prove the problem was not caused by my code.